# Enum Example Explanation

Tags: java, scjp

Here is a program taken from the SCJP 6 example. Here, we create a `enum` with different coffee sizes, and declare a private variable called `ounces` to get the ounce value part of enumeration.

I was not able to understand the use of `getLidCode` method which is overriden. How would one access the `getLidCode` method?

```
package com.chapter1.Declaration;

enum CoffeSize {
    BIG(8), HUGE(10), OVERWHELMING(20) {
        public String getLidCode() {
            return "B";
        }
    };

    CoffeSize(int ounce) {
        this.ounce = ounce;
    }

    private int ounce;

    public int getOunce() {
        return ounce;
    }

    public void setOunce(int ounce) {
        this.ounce = ounce;
    }

    public String getLidCode() {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class Prog7 {

    CoffeeSize size;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Prog7 p = new Prog7();
            p.size = CoffeeSize.OVERWHELMING;

            System.out.println(p.size.getOunces());

            //p.size.getLidCode(); ? is this correct way
        }
    }
```

Comment: To be short, yes it is the right way. `p.size.getLidCode();` gives you 'B'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes more sense if you space it out a bit more:

```
enum CoffeSize {
    BIG(8),
    HUGE(10),
    OVERWHELMING(20) {
        public String getLidCode() {
            return "B";
        }
    };
    // rest of enum code here
}
```

Only `OVERWHELMING` is overriding `getLidCode()`.

You would access it via this approach (using your code):

```
System.out.println(p.size.getLidCode());
```

The reason for this:  `p.size` is type `CoffeSize`, of which it has the method `getLidCode()`.  It will print the value of the overridden method, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not overly familiar with `enum`'s, but I believe the answer to your question is this:

There are two types of Lids, Lid A and B. Since B is right after the third declaration of standard sizes of coffees (`OVERWHELMING`), whenever `getLidCode()` is called on an `CoffeeSize`, and it matches `20`, it will return Lid `B`. If there are any other, manually set, sizes, such as 12 or 14, or `BIG` or `HUGE`, it will return `A`.

So basically, Lid B means it's a standard lid for overwhelming coffees. If a customer asks for a 12 ounce, or 18 ounce, or any other ounces of coffee, or for a `BIG` or `HUGE` coffee, they get a Lid A.

In conclusion:

```
 p.size = CoffeeSize.BIG;
 System.out.println(p.size.getOunces()); // Outputs "8"
 System.out.println(p.size.getLidType()); // Outputs "A"

 p.size = CoffeeSize.OVERWHELMING;
 System.out.println(p.size.getOunces()); // Outputs "20"
 System.out.println(p.size.getLidType()); // Outputs "B"

 p.size = CoffeeSize(12);
 System.out.println(p.size.getOunces()); // Outputs "12"
 System.out.println(p.size.getLidType()); // Outputs "A"

 p.setOunce(20);
 System.out.println(p.size.getOunces()); // Outputs "20"
 System.out.println(p.size.getLidType()); // Outputs "B"
```

Comment: You're on the right track.  The only catch is that you can't instantiate an enum in that fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Method `getLidCode` normally returns constant "A".  For `CoffeSize.BIG` and `CoffeSize.HUGE`, it is not overriden, so this is the value they will return.  However, for `CoffeSize.OVERWHELMING` it's overriden and it will return "B".

If you think of enums as classes and their enum values as instances of that class, enums allows method overriding on a per-object basis.  This is not possible with regular classes/objects.

This could also have been implemented as:

```
enum CoffeSize {
    BIG(8,"A"), HUGE(10,"A"), OVERWHELMING(20,"B");

    CoffeSize(int ounce,String lidCode) {
        this.ounce= ounce ;
        this.lidCode= lidCode ;
    }

    private int ounce;
    private String lidCode;

    public int getOunce() {
        return this.ounce ;
    }
    public void setOunce(int ounce) {
        this.ounce= ounce ;
    }
    public String getLidCode() {
        return this.lidCode ;
    }
}
```

Note that to make this alternate implementation more equivalent to the original one, no `setLidCode` method was defined.

The true power of this mechanism can be appreciated more easily in the following example, though:

```
enum BinaryOperation {
    ADDITION("+",1) {
        public double operate(double a,double b) {
            return a + b ;
        }
    },
    SUBTRACTION("-",1),
    MULTIPLICATION("*",2) {
        public double operate(double a,double b) {
            return a * b ;
        }
    },
    DIVISION("/",2),
    POWER("**",3);

    BinaryOperation(String repr,int priority) {
        this.repr= repr ;
        this.priority= priority ;
    }

    private String repr;
    private int priority;

    public String toString() {
        return this.repr ;
    }
    public int getPriority() {
        return this.priority ;
    }
    public double operate(double a,double b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException() ;
    }
}
```

`SUBTRACTION`, `DIVISION`, and `POWER` will throw an exception when their `operate` method is invoked (for some reason, only commutative operations have been implemented at this point).  However, `BinaryOperation.ADDITION.operate(3.5,2.1)` and `BinaryOperation.MULTIPLICATION.operate(4.5,2.0)` will return the expected values (5.6 and 9.0 respectively).  This also answers your question about usage.  Yes, your tentative example is correct.

**There is no simple OO way of implementing this using fields or other mechanisms.**

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is getOunce and not getOunces .
The following is the correct usage .

```
public class Prog7 {

CoffeSize size;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Prog7 p = new Prog7 ();
p.size = CoffeSize .OVERWHELMING;

System.out.println(p.size.getOunce());

System.out.println(p.size.getLidCode());
```

}

}

This would give the output as :

20

B